# Activating chair's gas lift?

Tags: furniture

I've ordered a [chair from Argos](http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Product/partNumber/6178077/Trail/searchtext%3EMANAGER+CHAIR.htm), however, after assembly, the gas lift fails to elevate the chair -in fact, pulling the lever on the side seems to have no effect at all (it just swings back & forth). The seat support seems to have a cylinder marked x <--> 1, however that also fails to make any effect.

Is the gas lift needs to be activated separately, or am I missing something obvious here? (chair is already a replacement, previous one had the same problem, so I'm assuming it's not manufacturer problem)

Terribly sorry for the newb question, would really appreciate constructive suggestions.

Comment: This is a bit off topic for Home Improvement. Have you tried contacting the company's customer support?

Comment: I did, they put me on hold until my card ran out of credit (~15 mins). I'm sorry for being a newb, but I was really looking forward to be able to use my computer sitting. Would really appreciate any help

Comment: Did you consult the manual/instructions?

Comment: This is argos we are talking about. A chair is part of the home! Vote to reopen! ikea gas lift sympathy pains.

Comment: @Magpie Would you hire a contractor to fix your chair? If you'd like to propose a change in the site scope, feel free to ask on meta, but I personally agree that this question is OT even though it would mean more rep for me to have it opened.

Comment: No but some people would. My last landlady hired not one, but two joiners to put together an ikea desk so I had one for when I moved in. I could not believe it and I also caught them them laughing about it as they came in. As it goes, people have different thresholds for what they view as a challenge! If I come on an ask a beginner programming or mathematics question should my post be closed? What defines a beginner anyway? I can plaster a wall but it took me a while to figure out the meaning behind the dodgy ikea arrows, in the end i just threw the instructions away and i have my chair now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically there is a valve opened by the lever pressing on the top center of the chair cylinder.  Maybe you need to push instead of pull, or maybe the lever needs to be pulled out before you use it.  They all have a different design.